# Currency formatting in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, currency

I am using apex:outputfield to display a currency field e.g. **EUR 1.005,22**. However there is a requirement from the client that they don't want to see the currency alongside the price rather separately e.g. **1.005,22**. I have tried apex:outputtext but it's not working since it's not possible to use the format '#.##0,00'. Is there a way in visualforce to just remove the currency?

**Update**:
I ended wrapping my class and doing manually the conversion in the apex controller. This is far from an optimal solution as this would require mapping every time I add a locale. Hopefully salesforce will sometime allow more granular formatting on numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `outputField` and using the Salesforce object, use a wrapper class in your controller.

For example:

```
public class MyObjectWrapper {
    public SObject myObject{get;set;}
    public String currency{get;set;}
}
```

Then in the constructor, you set `myObject` to be your object and `currency` to be `String.valueOf(myObject.Currency_Field__c)`

Then in the Visualforce page, you can use `apex:outputText`

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I am not accepting your answer since it does not answer my question. Thank you for your time anyway.

Comment: Seriously? There is no way in Visualforce to do this. I provided you with a valid solution.